# Prevent URL editing by users to restrict access to server's resources

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, express

I'm using node.js and express to serve html files which uses SSL encryption. But i noticed that users can change the url ie. if url is `https://localhost/index,html`, to `https://localhost/anyother.html`.How do i disable editing of url by users so that they cannot access any other html files of my server.

Comment: how looks the routing in your express-app?

Comment: it looks like res.redirect(302,'/views/index.html'); basically I'm just using redirect function.

Comment: there are probably some things like app.use( or app.route(...! i would just return a `res.end(404)` for everything which is not the base-path or index.html...

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Clients can ask for whatever they like.

If you want to limit who the server will give the files to, use an authentication / authorization system. Identify the user (e.g. with a password) and then decide if you want to respond with the file or a `403 Forbidden`.

Comment: do you really need an authorization system to decide inside an express app, which files to serve, and which not???

Comment: It doesn't have to be built into the express app itself, but (absent of any existing auth/authz system you have in place) that would probably be the simplest approach.